# Документация java совсем нубский вопрос

Tags: java

Сразу прошу прощения за такой тупой вопрос. Есть документация java по методам, вот пример

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Я нашёл нужный мне метод, например sort

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прочитал, он сортирует массив в порядке возрастания. То что надо.

А где посмотреть как его применять?

Я попытался, но java мне написала что такого метода не существует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А как делаете вы?** Читаете документацию, потом находите нужный метод, потом его название вбиваете в Google чтобы увидеть пример кода? Вот как я могу угадать, куда вставить этот метод, если для массива он не работает

Comment: `Arrays.sort(array);` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `sort` можно вызвать в интерфейсе `Arrays`, по примеру вашего кода вы можете вызвать его так:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

По поводу документации - находить интерфейсы/методы рядовом разработчику чаще всего не приходится в доке или гугле. Многое приходит с изучением Java Core и опытом.

При чтении документации смотрите шапку, там указан интерфейс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы там перепутали класс Array и непосредственно  массив (не расширяемая структура  наполненная  в вашем случае примитивами - типа int).Это  разные вещи.
Есть класс - Array (),  у которого есть методы  как у каждого класса
Есть структура хранения данных -array -это не класс, это способ хранения нескольких  данных.

Answer (score 1):

Используй:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```